# ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm trying to create a new Entity into the Database (H2) with the following format:

```
package eapli.base.customermanagement.domain;

import eapli.framework.domain.model.AggregateRoot;
import eapli.framework.domain.model.DomainEntities;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="Customer")
public class Customer implements AggregateRoot<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long customerId;

    @Embedded
    private PhoneNumber customerPhoneNumber;
    @Embedded
    private CustomerGender customerGender;
    @Embedded
    private CustomerBirthDate customerBirthDate;
    @Embedded
    private CustomerName customerName;
    @Embedded
    private CustomerVAT customerVAT;
    @Embedded
    private CustomerEmail customerEmail;


    public Customer(final PhoneNumber customerPhoneNumber, final CustomerBirthDate customerBirthDate, final CustomerName customerName, final CustomerGender customerGender, final CustomerVAT customerVAT, final CustomerEmail customerEmail) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        this.customerPhoneNumber = customerPhoneNumber;
        this.customerGender = customerGender;
        this.customerBirthDate = customerBirthDate;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.customerVAT = customerVAT;
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }

    public Customer() {

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return DomainEntities.hashCode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sameAs(Object other) {

        if(! (other instanceof Customer)){
            return false;
        }

        final Customer that =(Customer) other;

        if(this == that){
            return true;
        }

        return identity().equals(that.identity()) && customerGender.equals(that.customerGender) &&
                customerName.equals(that.customerName) &&
                customerEmail.equals(that.customerEmail) &&
                customerVAT.equals(customerVAT) &&
                customerPhoneNumber.equals(customerPhoneNumber) &&
                customerBirthDate.equals(that.customerBirthDate);
    }

    @Override
    public Long identity() {
        return customerId;
    }
}
```

However the following erro appears:

```
15:02:16.709 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02

15:02:16.709 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02

15:02:16.709 [main] ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Customer (customerId, customerDate, customerEmail, customergender, customerName, indicatives, pNumber, customerVAT) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]

15:02:16.709 [main] ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Customer (customerId, customerDate, customerEmail, customergender, customerName, indicatives, pNumber, customerVAT) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]
Something unexpected has happened and the application will terminate. Please check the logs.

15:02:16.718 [main] ERROR e.b.a.c.console.BaseApplication - javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are the tables created?

Comment: The customer table wasn't created. JPA is supposed to generate automatically right?

Comment: No only if you configure that